# Birt date and filter parameters

Tags: mysql, report, birt

I have created a birt report that do the following

- Filter report by date range
- Filter report by ID

Both are working but the problem is I can't combine this 2 parameters to make it a multiple reports.

My code

```
today = new Date(); //sample database ends in May 2005
//today = new Date(); //real "today" value if not using sample database
df = new Packages.java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
today = df.format(today);

if (params["Date Range"].value == "Custom Range"){
this.queryText = this.queryText + " where smartcomp.service.time_in between '" + params["StartDate"].value + "' and '" + params["EndDate"].value + "'";
}
else{
    if (params["Date Range"].value == "Last 6 Months"){
        rangeStart = DateTimeSpan.subDate(today, 0, 6, 0);
    }
    else if (params["Date Range"].value == "Last 12 Months"){
        rangeStart = DateTimeSpan.subDate(today, 0, 12, 0);
    }
    else{
        rangeStart = DateTimeSpan.subDate(today, 2, 0, 0);
    }


rangeStart = df.format(rangeStart);

this.queryText = this.queryText + " where smartcomp.service.time_in between '" + rangeStart + "' and '" + today + "'"
}


if( params["NewParameter2"].value != "(AllEmployee)" ){

this.queryText = this.queryText + " where employee.employee_id = " + params["NewParameter2"].value
}
```

P.S. The problem in that answer before (duplicate reason) was , that's php and this is birt + java, I knew how to combine both where clause in sql but I don't know how in birt.

Comment: Looks like you have two where clauses. You can only have one. So, the second one needs to be "and table.field = param", rather than where. It gets tricky if you want to have just one, either one, or both, as your code has to keep track of where you are.

Comment: Hmm can you please tell me how to combine both parameter in this statement, since I'm not familiar with this language unlike sql

Comment: CargoMeister gave you the answer: replace " **where** employee.employee_id = " with " **and** employee.employee_id = ". But you would rather make use of dataset query parameters instead of building the query in beforeOpen script. It would be easier to design and to maintain and more secured (SQLIA)

Comment: where smartcomp.service.time_in between date1 and date1 and smartcomp.service.time_in between time1 and time2